# Pickadate.js form submit issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, date

I am using `pickadate.js`. Following is the CODE :-

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Training", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "FTrain" }))
            {
 <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">From Date</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @type = "text", @Id = "txtFromdt" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm theming-btn waves-effect" value="Save"/>
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    // Materialize Date Picker
    var pickerinput = $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 100, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        onClose: function () {
            if (jq.isFunction(window.onCloseDatePickerCustom)) {
                onCloseDatePickerCustom();
            }
        }

    });
```

When i click the submit button, the form doesn't get submitted. My PC date format is `MM/dd/yyyy`.

The form gets submitted if i select date like `01/05/2015` & it doesn't get submitted when date is like this `30/05/2015`.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: what is wrong in this question to get minus points?

Comment: No idea.. Are you getting any inline response at all regarding the failure?

Comment: I get the DatePicker highlighted & it also opens up DatePicker when hitting the Submit Button & there is no error in console.

Comment: That's a pain.  Sounds like the pickadate function being called in the onClose is suppressing the error.  Only thing I can think of is to open up the pickadate js and add a bunch of debug to that function.